# Vertex snapping issue

Tags: vertices, edges, snapping

Blender 4

Trying to slide an edge and have the vertex snap to nearest but the sliding vertex just slows down as it gets near the target vertex. I can do it the slow way and not slide the whole edge but this would be so much fast[image]er. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the sliding is based on a percentage of the edge length for each vertex independently. The value goes from -1.0 (towards the vertex on one side of the edge) to 1.0 (towards the vertex on the other side), and 0.0 represents the original location.

Since the vertex on the right has a shorter edge compared to the other vertices, its movement will seem slower than the rest, but all of the vertices will reach the end of the edge at the same time.

*Edge Slide* has an alternative mode, *Even*, that will cause the sliding edge to take the shape of the edge loop before or after it. To enable *Even* mode, press <kbd>E</kbd> while the *Edge Slide* operator is active. To switch between the edge loops to match, press <kbd>F</kbd> (short for *Flipped*).

In summary, after triggering the *Edge Slide* operator, press <kbd>E</kbd>. If the edge is not shaped the way you want, press <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: Edge Slide]

Comment: Ahh, fantastic! Thanks so much, that solves it. Appreciate your taking the time.

Comment: You're welcome!